# Vim in xterm : Mouse cursor not changing based on mouse mode

Tags: vim, xterm, urxvt

When I use vim with gnome-terminal or yakuake, and I have mouse on ( `set mouse+=a` ), then I see an arrow as mouse pointer, and when I have mouse off, then the "insert" sign as mouse pointer. 
However, in xterm (and urxvt), I see only mouse pointer. How to ensure that I see the distinction in xterm as well? Or if not using mouse, then some other clearly visible distinction?

Comment: Have you looked at `:help termcap-cursor-shape`?

Comment: Is it possible to send the escape sequence mentioned via a command? Sorry not much of vim-settings expert, i use vim for fast movement/editing mostly.
Also, this should be noted for other readers, if this works, it would only be for cursor and would not fix the mouse pointer issue I mention in the question

Comment: Oops, my mistake. I don't think console Vim can change the mouse shape. What you're seeing is almost certainly a feature of the terminals themselves.

Answer (score 0):

vim does have a feature for changing the mouse appearance (see [term_cursor_shape](http://sourceforge.net/p/vim/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/src/term.c#l3475)) but it depends upon names normally not found in a termcap description: `SI` and `EI` (vim uses termcap names, even though termcap is rare compared to terminfo).  The usual names are `vi` (invisible), `ve` (normal) and `vs` (very visible).

If you happen to know a control sequence that works, you can use it in the corresponding `t_SI` and `t_EI` settings within vim.

Here are a few links to help:

- *[Standard equivalents for t_SI t_EI?](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/vim_dev/biVcXiYcLRw/zumrjo6gP4oJ)*
- *[Vim documentation: term](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/term.html)*

Outside of the documented vi/ve/vs, you are unlikely to find the same control sequences used for xterm versus urxvt.  xterm implements (see *[XTerm Control Sequences](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html)*) the `DECSCUSR` control which provides combinations of blinking/nonblinking and block/underline cursors.

Comment: As the above comments suggest, the term_cursor_shape isn't for the mouse cursor, but the terminal cursor.

Comment: The OP wants to see a distinct cursor in insert-mode.  vim documents a way to do that.